# Which valve turns off my homes main water supply?

Tags: shutoff

Trying to turn off water supply to my home. It is next to my water heater. See photo. Which valve is it?

[image]

Comment: what is preventing you from turning off the valves one at a time?

Comment: Well, two of them are yellow gas valves, if really having trouble sorting out what pipe is what...and in freezing areas it's common to have both the main shutoff and water meter inside the house, (there is usually a very inconvenient and often poorly functioning valve down a 6 foot hole in the street, but that's rarely useful, so there's a main valve for normal use just inside the basement.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal The yellow valves seem to transition to what looks to me like copper pipe -- isn't that inappropriate/banned for natural gas use?

Comment: @Armand It's very common (though possibly not in new work) for Propane Gas. I don't have either at present and haven't ever had Natural Gas available anywhere I was needing to update it. Looks gas to me.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, it's fine for propane, but from what I read online natural gas degrades copper pipe over time, leading to leaks. Perhaps the odorant reacts with the copper? I agree that the dope on the threaded fittings and the regulator look like gas.

Comment: @Ruskes - No, the shutoff is not always outside the house, and is not always (though may be) near where the water comes in.  My current house - rancher with a crawl space - brings the main line into the crawl space from the street, then over to the middle of the house (20' run) where the main shutoff is located, next to the hot water tank.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to be sure, I suspect the true main shutoff is outside, perhaps by the water meter or underground in freezing areas, and I can't make out flow direction arrows on anything, but if you turn off both of those valves that probably will do it.

[image]

One alone may do the house, the other might be for something like an irrigation system, or fire sprinklers - it's not clear from the picture. But that PRV is normally on the house interior plumbing feed line. If you can find the arrows on it, the one on the incoming side of it should be the main.

Comment: Every house I've lived in has had the main shutoff inside the house, where it's readily accessible by the homeowner.  It's not always right where the main water line enters the house.  There's also the shutoff by the meter, which is usually not home-owner accessible.

Comment: @SteveSh if you live in northern states, the valve will be inside to protect from freezing. In sudden states it is outside.

Comment: Some houses have both! I have a main shut off inside the house (placed it there my own self when we went from a well to city water). There's also a shutoff in the meter box by the sidewalk. I bought a kerb key to open the meter box and shut the water off there, just for added convenience. I happen to live in a place where we get snow and freezing weather, too...

Answer (score 2):

The blue handle in the lower left next to the pressure regulator should turn off your water supply. Confirm by opening a faucet on the upper floor of your house.

Answer (score 0):

The main water valve is usually outside where water comes in to your home, but that depends where you live climate wise..

In your case it is the valve just before the pressure regulator (the tall part)

There is also a valve in the ground under the cover where the water meter is.